# Hibernate @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2") take out the hyphens '-' to 32 length character

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, uuid

I want to use Hibernate 5 @GenericGenerator strategy `uuid2` instead `uuid`, but `uuid2` has 32 character with 4 hyphens `'-'` and column type is `char(32)`. How could I take out the hyphens.

I do not want to use `uuid` as strategy, because `org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator` is "deprecated" for new use.

Here the code:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "sys")
public class Sys {
    private String id;
    private Date createTime;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "create_time")
    public Date getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** if I replace "-" in setter, it will cause an error:

```
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id.replace("-", "");
}
```

Here is the whole stacktrace:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-2  ]|ERROR|ExceptionMapperStandardImpl|HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.keytop.manage.common.entity.SysOrgUser was altered from b08fcbc8-474f-4673-91ee-761fd83991e6 to b08fcbc8474f467391ee761fd83991e6]
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: identifier of an instance of com.keytop.manage.common.entity.SysOrgUser was altered from b08fcbc8-474f-4673-91ee-761fd83991e6 to b08fcbc8474f467391ee761fd83991e6; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.keytop.manage.common.entity.SysOrgUser was altered from b08fcbc8-474f-4673-91ee-761fd83991e6 to b08fcbc8474f467391ee761fd83991e6
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:312)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.keytop.manage.common.service.SysOrgService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c36614a0.saveOrg(<generated>)
    at com.keytop.manage.common.controller.SysOrgController.saveOrg(SysOrgController.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.keytop.manage.framework.jwt.JwtAuthorizeFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthorizeFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.keytop.manage.common.entity.SysOrgUser was altered from b08fcbc8-474f-4673-91ee-761fd83991e6 to b08fcbc8474f467391ee761fd83991e6
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `id.replace ("-", "");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I had try this way, but it can not work. Here the error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.common.entity.Sys was altered from b08fcbc8-474f-4673-91ee-761fd83991e6 to b08fcbc8474f467391ee761fd83991e6`

Comment: sorry, can you post your whole stacktrace?

Comment: @ScaryWombat first of all, thx for answer my question. and i update the stacktrace infomation in question.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am looking at this backwards, but I would have thought that the `getId` should be changed not the `setId`

Comment: @ScaryWombat it can not be changed in getter, `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.keytop.manage.common.entity.SysOrgUser.id`

Comment: Sorry I could not help.

Comment: @ScaryWombat it's all right, u had helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

- Use `UUID` as the data type instead of the `String` type.
- It’s not a good idea to use VARCHAR(36) as a column type for UUIDs.Instead, we should use a BINARY(16) column. This minimizes the required value size (less bytes, no dashes) and index size.

  ```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
  private UUID id;
  ```
- If you want to avoid hyphens '-' you can convert uuid to hex value.

  ```
  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;
  @Transactional
  @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Collection<Sys> getSys() {
      Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT hex(s.id), s.name, s.createTime FROM Sys s");
      return (Collection<Sys>) query.getResultList();
  }
  ```

**I hope this solves your problem.**